# Cannot implement merge sort in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I'm new to algorithms, I've been trying to get the merge sort work, but it just won't give the right output. No compilation errors, but I guess it's just flawed somewhere, showing random values in output as the sorted array.

```
void merge_sort(int[], int, int);
void merge(int[], int, int, int);
void printarray(int[], int);

int main() {
    int Arr[100], num_of_elements;
    cout << "Enter the number of elements (max 100): ";
    cin >> num_of_elements;
    cout << "Enter array elements: \n";
    for (int i = 0;i < num_of_elements;++i)
        cin >> Arr[i];
    merge_sort(Arr, 0, num_of_elements - 1);
    cout << "\nAfter Sorting (by Merge Sort):\n";
    printarray(Arr, num_of_elements);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

void merge_sort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        merge_sort(arr, left, mid);
        merge_sort(arr, mid + 1, right);
        merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }  
}

void merge(int arr[], int left, int mid, int right) {
    int i, j, k;

    /* Calculate the lengths of the subarrays and copy the elements into them */
    int lenght_left = mid - left + 1;
    int length_right = right - mid;
    int *leftarray = new int[lenght_left];
    int *rightarray = new int[length_right];
    for (i = 0;i < lenght_left;++i)
        leftarray[i] = arr[left + i];
    for (j = 0;j < length_right;++j)
        rightarray[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j];

    /* Reordering the elements in the original array */
    for (k = left, i = 0, j = 0;k <= right;++k) {
        if (leftarray[i] <= rightarray[j])
            arr[k] = leftarray[i++];
        else
            arr[k] = rightarray[j++];
    }  

    /* Copy remaining elements into the array */
    while (i < lenght_left)
        arr[k] = leftarray[i++];
    while (j < length_right)
        arr[k] = rightarray[j++];
    delete[](leftarray);
    delete[](rightarray);
}

void printarray(int arr[], int num) {
    cout << "Displaying Elements in array: \n";
    for (int i = 0;i < num;i++)
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
}
```

Comment: When creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's important to actually make it *complete*, and show how the functions you have are used, and what input you pass to them as well as the expected and actual output. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: What do you mean by `showing random values in output as the sorted array.`? Do you mean that the array doesn't get sorted at all, gets partially sorted or it gets filled with garbage data? If the last, then you have a memory issue somewhere (=> debugger). Can you also show us the call of your merge sort function (including how you initialize your array and pass it to you function)?

Comment: Although this doesn't have much to do with your question, but please learn how to properly code in C++. You're basically writing code in C, just replacing `printf` with `cout` and `malloc` with `new`, and then calling it C++. That's so wrong on so many levels though. No offense, just a personal advice, but you really should learn the proper C++ way of doing things, like using vectors, STL algorithms, templates, etc. These are essential if you want to write quality code. C++ is **not** C.

Comment: @adam10603 I appreciate the advice, I'm just learning C++ right now, haven't have gotten to templates and everything already. Would you help with some reference links from where I can catch up and become better and more C++ inclined? I'd appreciate it a lot! :D

Comment: Get some [good book of c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0):

In your `merge` function:

```
/* Reordering the elements in the original array */
for (k = left, i = 0, j = 0; k <= right; ++k) {
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
// It should be i < lenght_left && j < length_right
    if (leftarray[i] <= rightarray[j])
        arr[k] = leftarray[i++];
    else
        arr[k] = rightarray[j++];
}
```

The condition you're using to control the loop is not right, the condition should be with respect to your `leftarray` and `rightarray`, it should be, that when either of the arrays reach to their end, so change your condition to `i < lenght_left && j < length_right`.

And when copying the remaining elements in the same function:

```
/* Copy remaining elements into the array */
while (i < lenght_left)
    arr[k] = leftarray[i++];
//     ^^^
while (j < length_right)
    arr[k] = rightarray[j++];
//     ^^^
```

Here, you forgot to increment `k`, change them to `k++`.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes you are making:

1. You need to check that you don't go over the length of the array when you're merging

   Namely instead of:

   ```
   for (k = left, i = 0, j = 0;k <= right;++k)
   ```

   You should have:

   ```
   for (k = left, i = 0, j = 0;k <= right && i <lenght_left && j<length_right;++k)
   ```
2. You forget to increase the array counter when adding the leftover elements.
   Namely:

   ```
   while (i < lenght_left)
       arr[k] = leftarray[i++];
   while (j < length_right)
       arr[k] = rightarray[j++];
   ```

   You should have:

   ```
   while (i < lenght_left)
       arr[k++] = leftarray[i++];
   while (j < length_right)
       arr[k++] = rightarray[j++];
   ```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Although I'm just wondering why not checking **i** and **j** to be less than respective lengths is needed. The loop for **k** should only run for as many elements are there in the subarray in the merge() method?

Comment: can you answer it?

Comment: Think of the case left part is: 10 11 12 and right part is 1 2 3. Then what will happen is that you'll add 10 11 12 in the arr adn you'll check the offset of left array which will be out of bounds.

Comment: But then just this condition `i <lenght_left && j<length_right` will be false, as either of the parts has been reached to their end, and there'll not be any out of bound accessing of the elements.